# Cropping an image fetched using Picasso?

Tags: android, android-imageview, crop, picasso

I have the following code in my adapter class -

```kotlin
 override fun onBindViewHolder(vendorsHolder: VendorsHolder, i: Int) {
        val model = miniVendorModels[i]
        Picasso.get().load(model.bannerPicture).into(vendorsHolder.vendorImageView)
...
...
...
```

The pictures I get from the model are too wide for me.

How can I crop them to my own dimentions? I want to crop it for like the 50% of the start of them (from the left) and show them only.

Edit -

here is my XML -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/vendors_row_item_root_layout"
    android:layout_width="152dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/search_image_contact_cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        tools:layout_height="160dp">

        <com.twoverte.views.CropImageView
            android:id="@+id/vendors_row_item_imageview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            tools:src="@drawable/kikiandggcover" />


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Picasso.get()
       .load(model.bannerPicture)
       .resize(imgWidth, imgHeight).centerInside()
       .into(vendorsHolder.vendorImageView);
```

Comment: added my XML file